# How would one go about integrating $\int x^2y'dx$ ?? - Implicit Integration??

Tags: calculus, integration

My friend and I are attempting to do some crazy integral stuff which he came up with but I am still having trouble getting my head around, but here's the general gist of what he is trying to get at:

Propose we have a function: $f(x)={\sqrt{x}}$. This of course is easy enough to integrate in of itself but what we're trying to figure out is if we make it so ${y^2}=x$ then integrate both sides of the function, can we still get the same answer.

---

Here's how he computed it:

$y^2=x$

$y^2y'=xy'$

$\int y^2y'dx=\int xy'dx$

The $\int y^2y'dx$ can be solved using u-substitution because recall that y is a function with respect to x rather than a constant. Additionally, the $\int xy' dx$ can be solved using integration by parts where one can arrive at $\int xy'dx=xy-\int y dx$ note how that $\int ydx = Y$ so now we have:

$\frac{1}{3}y^3=xy-Y$

Now we solve for $Y$:

$Y=xy-\frac{1}{3}y^3$

$Y=\frac{2}{3}y^3$

This is the correct answer, but it's just in terms of y, substituting $y=\sqrt{x}$ into the equation, we arrive at:

$Y=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ which is the correct answer if we'd just used the power rule of integrals. Now that was just an example to see if it worked the true problem arrises from when we take a new line, notably:

$x^2+y^2=1$ and "implicitly integrate", note the quotations, just a made up name.

---

If we do what we normally do:

$x^2y'+y^2y'=y'$

$\int x^2y'dx + \int y^2y'dx = \int y'dx$

$\int x^2y'dx + \frac{1}{3}y^{3} = y$

---

Our problem occurs when we attempt to integrate that $x^2$ guy. After preforming 2 integrations by parts the integral ends up containing $Y$ which is just something that we don't want to happen. So if anyone knows what to do and we're just not seeing something painfully obvious please do tell.

### Addendum

---

This is work we've done on $\int x^2y'dx$ and some other stuff as per the request of StinkingBishop:

If $u=x$, $du=dx$ and $dv=xy'$, $v=\int xy'dx$ and then by subbing into the IBP formula we arrived at:

$x(xy-Y)-\int (xy-Y)dx$ which is where problems arise because now we're integrating $Y$.

Additionally, we tried taking derivatives and manipulating the equation but the furtherest we got was:

(Differentiation) $2x+2yy'=0$ then $y'=\frac{-x}{y}$

$x^2+y^2=1$

$\frac{x^2}{y}+y=\frac{1}{y}$

(Recall: $y'=\frac{-x}{y}$) $-xy'+y=\frac{1}{y}$

(Integrating) $-(xy-Y)+Y=\int \frac{dx}{y}$

and this is where we got stuck again, if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Excellent first question! My only bit of care would be to remember that $y$ is a function of $x$ still, and integral in $x$ in that case would need some care.

Comment: It would help (me at least!) to see your work on integrating $\int x^2y'dx$ and the exact  point where you are stuck. From 30,000 ft it looks to me that you have invented a new method and have just hit its limitations, but I may be wrong. One reason for this thinking is that you somehow need to end with something that will be able to produce $\pi/4$ when you substitute the limits $0, 1$ and what you've got so far looks incapable of doing that. *Of course* you may substitute $x^2=1-y^2$ but this will only prove that $\frac{1}{3}y^3-y=\frac{1}{3}y^3-y$ :(

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is that you have not chosen [a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) :-/

Comment: @LeeMosher There I have picked a better title, or I at least hope so :)

Comment: @StinkingBishop There I edited it, if it causes more confusion let me know but that's all we've done, we worked on this together only really last night.

Comment: If the method goes nowhere, then this won't matter, but you need to be _very_ careful with equating indefinite integrals, as the equation you get is only true modulo a constant.  The alternative is to use definite integrals, which is also the reason why the first problem didn't come up against this issue: your indefinite integrals can all be reinterpreted as the definite integrals $\int_0^x$ (with the appropriate re-labeling of variables in the integrands).  I don't think the equation in the second problem will be so lucky (essentially because $(0,0)$ doesn't lie on the circle)

Comment: Now I understand what you meant by "integral ends by containing Y", but I am none the wiser how to help. You can use IBP in a different way ($u=x^2, dv=y'dx, v=y, du=2xdx$ to reach $\int xydx$) but again it is not clear how to proceed. To use trigonometric substitution here is possible but it won't be your method anymore (it would beg the question why not use it to start with). So... sorry, I don't know, it looks to me that you did indeed hit a limitation of your method.